# how do I get my print function to "remember" my previous statement

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

word_list_easy = ["word", "apple", "banana", "cheese"]

difficulty = str(input("Please enter difficulty: Easy, Medium or Hard. "))
difficulty = difficulty.upper()
empty = ("")

if difficulty == ("EASY"):
    maximum = len(word_list_easy)
    maximum = maximum - 1
    #makes a random variable that cant excede the length of the list
    random = random.randint(0,maximum)
    random_word = word_list_easy[random]
    #chooses a random word in the list
    word_length = len(random_word)

    for i in range (word_length):
        #shows how many letters there are
        print("_", end=" ")
    print("There are ", word_length ,"letters in the word")
    #sets how many tries you get. (later will make graphical)
    tries = 5
    while tries >= 1:
        #will repeat untill out of tries
        geussed_letter = input("Enter your geuss of the letter ")
        #sets geussed letter to nothing 
        while len(geussed_letter) > 1:
                  geussed_letter = input("Enter one letter that you think is in the word ")
        while (geussed_letter) == (""):
            geussed_letter = input("Please enter a letter ")
                  #if the letter is in the word,
        if (geussed_letter) in (random_word):
            print("You geussed correctly")
            #finding the index of letter in word

            new_random_word = random_word.replace(geussed_letter, empty)
            new_len_word = len(random_word)
            #find the length of the new word to repeat the "_" lines for length of new word
            index_of_letter = random_word.find(geussed_letter)
            rest = len(new_random_word) - (index_of_letter)
            for i in range (index_of_letter):
                print("_", end=" ")
            print(geussed_letter)
            for i in range (rest):
                print("_", end=" ")
            print(" ", end="\n")

        else:
            print("Sorry but your geuss was wrong ")
            tries = tries - 1
            print("You have",tries," tries left")

        if (new_random_word) == (""):
            print("Congratulations, you geussed the correct word. It was ", random_word)
```

im trying to create a hangman game. its not done however I have multiple problems which I have difficulty fixing. First of all I would like `print("_" end=" ")` to output the previous guessed letter too instead of only the recent guessed letter. my other problem is that when the word is for example banana, the print statement only prints the first "a" if the a is guessed. I understand my title isn't very detailed but I wasn't sure how to word it. Thanks

Comment: Append each guess onto a list/set and then print that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to go about it:

```
random_word = 'bananna'
length = len (random_word)
guessed_letters = ['_'] * length
print ('  ' + ' '.join (guessed_letters))

guessed_letter = 'a'
for index in range (length):
    if guessed_letter == random_word [index] :
        guessed_letters [index] = guessed_letter
print ('  ' + ' '.join (guessed_letters))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is just removing the letter you want to keep. Instead of replacing it with `empty`, should make a list where it includes `'_'`  for all of the letters as long as the length of the word is. So, instead of:

```py
for i in range (word_length):
    #shows how many letters there are
    print("_", end=" ")
```

You'd do:

```py
guessed_word = ["_"]
for i in range(word_length-1):
    guessed_word.append("_")
print(guessed_word)
```

to make a list that contains underscores for every element for the same length. Then, when they guess the correct letter, just replace the correct spot of `guessed_word` with the `guessed_letter`.

```py
guessed_word[index_of_letter] = guessed_letter
print(guessed_word)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: hey, thanks for this. I was just wondering where would I put those last lines of code about the list. I really dislike the list part of coding so this would help me alot

Comment: @KamilLeocadie-Olsen No Problem! If you have any problems with list coding, you can just look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)